# How do you control the lifetime of a Rook server?

Tags: r, http, rscript, r-rook-package

I am new to R and to Rook. I am able to successfully run Rook in a browser when I run from RTerm or from RStudio. However, when I run from RScript I get connection refused. My guess is that RScript runs my script and exits the script.

So how would I package up a R Rook application for end users that does not require starting RTerm and manually exiting after the user closes the web pages? Is there a way to handle this using HTTP 1.1 keep alive?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh... It looks like there is an example of doing this. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rrook/_da0Xmf8ZWY/SF0k1OvYzGoJ and open the conversation  from Sven and download simplerookapp.zip. I have not yet had a chance to verify it, but it does look promising.